# PPTP VPN 778 Error in all OS without iOS

Tags: vpn, pptpd

I deployed a PPTP VPN tunnel on my Bandwagonhost's VPS with Debian 7, When I use my phone(iOS),They all can worked well. But When I use my PC(Win7 or WinXP or Android),It noticed me that:778 Error.

How Can I Work It Out?

BTW: Running Debian7 Samba pptpd on this server. I also deployed ShadowSocks Python Server , Pure-FTPD , apache2 and PHP5.2 on this server.